# Copy Project from Cloud 2012 to Local 2012 & synchronize daily

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am new to TFS.

I have cloud TFS 2012. We are currently working on that TFS. We have another internal local TFS . I have created new project in local TFS. I want to copy files from remote TFS project to my local TFS project and then synchronize daily at specific time interval.

is there easy way to to do synchronization?

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to synchronization two tfs.

Try  TFS integration tool http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

More useful links.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/05/11/tfs-integration-tools-where-does-one-start-part-1.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2009/10/07/tfs-integration-platform-summary-of-links.aspx

Comment: The integration platform is the only way. Also, you'll need to keep your mappings between the two maintained. TFService regularly updates the work item definitions and your on premise won't have those template changes meaning your integration may/will break at some point in the future.

Also, from experience, the integration platform is flaky piece of software. Expect headaches and pain if you use it :-)